# Django - Apache2 can't load media files from media folder

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, apache

I installed an linux server with apache where I want to run my Django app. So I set everything up and when I started the app everything was shown to me except for the pictures.
I couldn't find a error inside my site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName MYHOST

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/mysite/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/mysite/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/media/

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

or inside my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/mysite/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

What I did was setting debug = True and inside linux console I run `python3 manage.py collectstatic` after reloading apache the website was shown with all its css and js but for every image request I get an error 404.

Inside my templates/base.html I call `{% load static %}`. I tried to replace it with `{% load staticfiles from static %}` but that crashed my entire app (err 500)
I use Django version 3.x and apache2

Comment: You have a typo in your Alias setup (`static` is there twice).

Comment: Oh yes.. thanks such a stupid error :D